# Creation of Programmatic Menu (Dynamic) PrimeFaces - Error in Redirect Submenu

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I need some support with this, I'm out of ideas of what can be:

I'm using JSF 2 and **Primefaces**, to develop a website where I need to dynamically create a **MenuBar**, I'm using the basic structure of the dynamic menus Primefaces (MenuModel):

DefaultMenuModel **->** DefaultSubMenu **->** DefaultMenuItem

For my page I am creating a session bean, where it is responsible for creating my menu (if it is necessary) and recreate (if any changes), everything is working perfectly, my menu is created with all parameters (outcome) and other methods (action).

**My problem is that when I click on various submenus within my menu, again and again, my menu is lost and my system throws an exception**

Examplain better:

By explaining better:

I'm clicking a submenu it redirects me to another page
This other page I click again on another submenu, which redirects me to another page,
And so forth....

***I'm using:***

**PrimeFaces 5.1**

**This is my Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.findMenuitem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:90)
at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.decode(BaseMenuRenderer.java:61)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1181)
at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(UIForm.java:225)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processDecodes(Layout.java:226)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.Layout.processDecodes(Layout.java:226)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(UIComponentBase.java:1176)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:933)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:242)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:216)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:132)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:352)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.adr.jpa.JPAFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.invokeNextFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.invokeNextFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.invokeNextFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.XSSParameterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:105)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.invokeNextFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.ford.fc.atd.servlet.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:63)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:75)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3288)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3254)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2163)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2091)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2074)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1512)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:255)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

**And This is my Bean Code:**

```
//more imports

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.primefaces.event.MenuActionEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultMenuModel;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.DefaultSubMenu;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuItem;
import org.primefaces.model.menu.MenuModel;

//more imports

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuBean extends BaseResourcePage {

    /**
     * Serial Id.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3250501071227237715L;

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final String LOG_FACILITY = MenuBean.class.getPackage().getName();


    @ManagedProperty(value="#{BEANAuth}")
    private BEANAuthBean BEANAuth;

    @Inject
    UserSession userSession;

    private MenuModel mainMenu;

    private MenuModel breadCrump;

    private CountryEntity selectedcountry = new CountryEntity();

    private static final String DOT_TITLE = ".title";

    private static final String MODIFY = "modify";

    private static final String VIEW = "view";

    public MenuModel getBreadCrumb() {
        if(this.userSession.getCountryUsed() != null && this.breadCrump == null) {
            Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getBreadCrumb = CREATE A BREADCRUMB");
            createHomeElementBreadcrumb();
        }

        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getBreadCrumb = In here");
        if(this.breadCrump != null) {
            Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getBreadCrumb = SIZE ELEMENTS " + this.breadCrump.getElements().size());
        }
        return this.breadCrump;
    }

    private void createHomeElementBreadcrumb() {

        DefaultMenuItem homeElement = new DefaultMenuItem();
        homeElement.setId("homeBreadcumb");
        homeElement.setValue("Home");
        homeElement.setTitle("Home");
        homeElement.setCommand("#{menuBean.doClearBreadCrumb}");
        homeElement.setParam("outcome", new String("homePage"));
        homeElement.setAjax(false); // TODO REMOVE AJAX TRANSACTION

        this.breadCrump = new DefaultMenuModel();
        this.breadCrump.addElement(homeElement);
    }

    public String doClearBreadCrumb(MenuActionEvent  event) {
        String outcome = event.getMenuItem().getParams().get("outcome").get(0);
        createHomeElementBreadcrumb();
        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "doClearBreadCrumb(MenuActionEvent) = OutCome : " + outcome);
        return outcome;
    }

    public String doClearBreadCrumb() {
        createHomeElementBreadcrumb();
        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "doClearBreadCrumb = OutCome : homePage");
        return "homePage";
    }

    public MenuModel getMenuModel() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        if(userSession.getCountryUsed() != null 
                && !userSession.getCountryUsed().equals(this.selectedcountry)) {
            Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getMenuModel = CREATE A MAIN MENU");
            this.selectedcountry = this.userSession.getCountryUsed().clone();
            createMenu();
        }
        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getMenuModel = In here");

        if(this.mainMenu != null) {
            Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "getMenuModel = SIZE ELEMENTS " + this.mainMenu.getElements().size());
        }

        return this.mainMenu;
    }

    private void createMenu() {
        this.mainMenu = new DefaultMenuModel();

        //TODO ACCESS MENU ????
        createDocumentAndAcceptsMenu();
        createJudicialAssignmentMenu();
        createAgreementMenu();
        createGeneralMenu();
        createReportsMenu();
        createPaymentFeesMenu();
        createPayLegalFeesMenu();
        createProcessesMenu();
        createRepossessionMenu();
        createRecordsMenu();
    }

    private void createDocumentAndAcceptsMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> documentAndAcceptsItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        documentAndAcceptsItems.put(new String("documentAndAccepts.acceptsProcess"), ACCEPTS_PROCESS);
        documentAndAcceptsItems.put(new String("documentAndAccepts.sendReceiveDocuments"), SEND_RECEIVE_DOCUMENTS);

        DefaultSubMenu documentAndAcceptsMenu = createMenuItems(documentAndAcceptsItems);
        documentAndAcceptsMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.documentAndAccepts"));
        documentAndAcceptsMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.documentAndAccepts") + "Id");


        this.mainMenu.addElement(documentAndAcceptsMenu);
    }

    private void createJudicialAssignmentMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> judicialAssignmentItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.lawyersAllocationByUser"), LAWYERS_ALLOCATION_BY_USER);
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.judgmentLawyerAndDetermination"), JUDGMENT_LAWYER_AND_DETERMINATION);
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.documentsRequestedList"), DOCUMENTS_REQUESTED_LIST);
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.generalProcessAndFollowUps"), GENERAL_PROCESSAND_FOLLOW_UPS);
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.preAssignmentFocus"), PRE_ASSIGNMENT_FOCUS);
        judicialAssignmentItems.put(new String("judicialAssignment.documentsRequestedBranch"), DOCUMENTS_REQUESTED_BRANCH);

        DefaultSubMenu judicialAssignmentMenu = createMenuItems(judicialAssignmentItems);
        judicialAssignmentMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.judicialAssignment"));
        judicialAssignmentMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.judicialAssignment") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(judicialAssignmentMenu);
    }

    private void createAgreementMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> agreementItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        agreementItems.put(new String("agreement.followAgreement"), FOLLOW_AGREEMENT);
        agreementItems.put(new String("agreement.agreement"), AGREEMENT);
        agreementItems.put(new String("agreement.monthlyAgreement"), MONTHLY_AGREEMENT);

        DefaultSubMenu agreementMenu = createMenuItems(agreementItems);
        agreementMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.agreement"));
        agreementMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.agreement") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(agreementMenu);
    }

    private void createGeneralMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> generalItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        generalItems.put(new String("general.branchRegion"), BRANCH_REGION);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.bucketsAging"), BUCKET_SAGING);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.filesSearch"), FILES_SEARCH);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.expenses"), EXPENSES);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.maintenanceControlFiles"), MAINTENANCE_CONTROL_FILES);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.keyTableMaintenance"), KEY_TABLE_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.workdaysMaintenance"), WORKDAYS_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.maintenanceMenu"), MAINTENANCE_MENU);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.parametersMaintenance"), PARAMETERS_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.percentageFeesMaintenance"), PERCENTAGE_FEES_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.tableSubkeyMaintenance"), TABLE_SUBKEY_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.userTypeMaintenance"), USER_TYPE_MAINTENANCE);
        generalItems.put(new String("general.documentationTutorial"), DOCUMENTATION_TUTORIAL);

        DefaultSubMenu generalMenu = createMenuItems(generalItems);
        generalMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.general"));
        generalMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.general") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(generalMenu);
    }

    private void createReportsMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> reportsItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.agingNoJudicialCollection"), AGING_NO_JUDICIAL_COLLECTION);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.agingLegalCollection"), AGING_LEGAL_COLLECTION);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.compass"), COMPASS);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.eventsOrCompass"), COMPASS_OR_NEWS);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.events"), EVENTS);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.legalExpenses"), LEGAL_EXPENSES);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.generalPayments"), GENERAL_PAYMENTS);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.harshDataReport"), HARSH_DATA_REPORT);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.assignmentsHistory"), ASSIGNMENTS_HISTORY);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.contractValuesHistory"), CONTRACT_VALUES_HISTORY);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.lawyerFees"), LAWYER_FEES);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.agenciesFees"), AGENCIES_FEES);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.listOfEmbargoedGoods"), LIST_OF_EMBARGOED_GOODS);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.reportOfSupervisor"), REPORT_OF_SUPERVISOR);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.paymentsByDate"), PAYMENTS_BY_DATE);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.reportBreakDownRecuperation"), REPORT_BREAK_DOWN_RECUPERATION);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.lawyerPaymentsSummary"), LAWYER_PAYMENTS_SUMMARY);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.stagesSummary"), STAGES_SUMMARY);
        reportsItems.put(new String("reports.summaryByEvents"), SUMMARY_BY_EVENTS);

        DefaultSubMenu reportsMenu = createMenuItems(reportsItems);
        reportsMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.reports"));
        reportsMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.reports") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(reportsMenu);
    }

    private void createPaymentFeesMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> paymentFeesItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        paymentFeesItems.put(new String("paymentFees.activationFees"), ACTIVATION_FEES);
        paymentFeesItems.put(new String("paymentFees.cancelPayFees"), CANCEL_PAY_FEES);
        paymentFeesItems.put(new String("paymentFees.paymentFeesGenerate"), PAYMENT_FEES_GENERATE);
        paymentFeesItems.put(new String("paymentFees.paymentFeesList"), PAYMENT_FEES_LIST);
        paymentFeesItems.put(new String("paymentFees.effectiveFeesPayment"), EFFECTIVE_FEES_PAYMENT);

        DefaultSubMenu paymentFeesMenu = createMenuItems(paymentFeesItems);
        paymentFeesMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.paymentFees"));
        paymentFeesMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.paymentFees") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(paymentFeesMenu);
    }

    private void createPayLegalFeesMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> payLegalFeesItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        payLegalFeesItems.put(new String("payLegalFees.payLegalFeesActivation"), PAY_LEGAL_FEES_ACTIVATION);
        payLegalFeesItems.put(new String("payLegalFees.cancelPayLegalFees"), CANCEL_PAY_LEGAL_FEES);
        payLegalFeesItems.put(new String("payLegalFees.generatePayLegalFees"), GENERATE_PAY_LEGAL_FEES);
        payLegalFeesItems.put(new String("payLegalFees.reportPayLegalFees"), REPORT_PAY_LEGAL_FEES);
        payLegalFeesItems.put(new String("payLegalFees.payLegalFees"), PAY_LEGAL_FEES);

        DefaultSubMenu payLegalFeesMenu = createMenuItems(payLegalFeesItems);
        payLegalFeesMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.payLegalFees"));
        payLegalFeesMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.payLegalFees") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(payLegalFeesMenu);
    }

    private void createProcessesMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> agreementItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.assignExternalAgencies"), ASSIGN_EXTERNAL_AGENCIES);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.specialEventChanges"), SPECIAL_EVENT_CHANGES);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.loadEvents"), LOAD_EVENTS);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.loadJudicialEvents"), LOAD_JUDICIAL_EVENTS);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.guarantorInquiry"), GUARANTOR_INQUIRY);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.legalCustomerInquiry"), LEGAL_CUSTOMER_INQUIRY);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.contractInquiry"), CONTRACT_INQUIRY);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.legalClaim"), LEGAL_CLAIM);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.embargoedGoods"), EMBARGOED_GOODS);
        agreementItems.put(new String("processes.sentence"), SENTENCE);

        DefaultSubMenu processesMenu = createMenuItems(agreementItems);
        processesMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.processes"));
        processesMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.processes") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(processesMenu);
    }

    private void createRepossessionMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> repossessionItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        repossessionItems.put(new String("repossession.vehicleStorage"), VEHICLE_STORAGE);
        repossessionItems.put(new String("repossession.repossessionReport"), REPOSSESSION_REPORT);
        repossessionItems.put(new String("repossession.repossessionVoluntarySurrender"), REPOSSESSION_VOLUNTARY_SURRENDER);

        DefaultSubMenu repossessionMenu = createMenuItems(repossessionItems);
        repossessionMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.repossession"));
        repossessionMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.repossession") + "Id");
        this.mainMenu.addElement(repossessionMenu);
    }

    private void createRecordsMenu() {
        Map<String, NavigationEnum> recordsItems = new HashMap<String, NavigationEnum>();
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.stages"), STAGES);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.usersDealerDEList"), USERS_DEALER_DE_LIST);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.dealerExternalAgenciesList"), DEALER_EXTERNAL_AGENCIES_LIST);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.postalCodesRangeExternalAgencies"), POSTAL_CODES_RANGE_EXTERNAL_AGENCIES);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.eventTableList"), EVENT_TABLE_LIST);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.externalAgenciesAndLawyersMaintenance"), EXTERNAL_AGENCIES_AND_LAWYERS_MAINTENANCE);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.maintenanceBusinessCategory"), MAINTENANCE_BUSINESS_CATEGORY);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.instituteMaintenance"),  INSTITUTE_MAINTENANCE);
        recordsItems.put(new String("records.steps"), STEPS);

        DefaultSubMenu recordMenu = createMenuItems(recordsItems);
        recordMenu.setLabel(getResourceAccessValue("menu.records"));
        recordMenu.setId(getResourceAccessValue("menu.records") + "Id");

        //TODO test for add or not a menu without a result inside
        if(!recordMenu.isRendered()) {
            this.mainMenu.addElement(recordMenu);
        }
    }


    private DefaultSubMenu createMenuItems(final Map<String, NavigationEnum> menuItens) {

        DefaultSubMenu defaultSubMenu = new DefaultSubMenu();   

        for (String keyItem : menuItens.keySet()) {
            String resourceRule = getResourceRuleMenu(keyItem);

            if(BEANAuth.hasResPermission(resourceRule)) {
                String destination = menuItens.get(keyItem).getDestination();

                DefaultMenuItem menuItem = new DefaultMenuItem();
                menuItem.setId(destination + "MenuItemID");
                menuItem.setValue(getResourceAccessValue(keyItem));
                menuItem.setTitle(getResourceAccessValue(new StringBuilder(keyItem).append(DOT_TITLE).toString()));
                menuItem.setCommand("#{menuBean.addElementBreadcrumByMenu}");
                menuItem.setParam("outcome", destination);
                menuItem.setAjax(false); // TODO REMOVE AJAX TRANSACTION
                menuItem.setImmediate(true);
                menuItem.setUpdate(":mainMenuForm, :breadCrumbForm");

                Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "createMenuItems = ID MENU ITEM " + menuItem.getId());
                defaultSubMenu.addElement(menuItem);
            }
        }

        defaultSubMenu.setRendered(!defaultSubMenu.getElements().isEmpty());
        return defaultSubMenu;
    }

    private String getResourceRuleMenu(String keyItem) {
        return new StringBuilder(keyItem).append(":").append(VIEW).append(",").append(keyItem).append(":").append(MODIFY).toString();
    }

    public String addElementBreadcrumByMenu(MenuActionEvent  event) {
        MenuItem menuItem = event.getMenuItem();
        String outcome = menuItem.getParams().get("outcome").get(0);
        createHomeElementBreadcrumb();
        createElementBreadcrum(menuItem, outcome);
        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "addElementBreadcrumByMenu(MenuActionEvent) = OutCome : " + outcome);
        return outcome;
    }

    public String addElementBreadcrumByMenuButton(MenuActionEvent  event) {
        MenuItem menuItem = event.getMenuItem();
        String outcome = menuItem.getParams().get("outcome").get(0);
        createElementBreadcrum(menuItem, outcome);
        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "addElementBreadcrumByMenuButton(MenuActionEvent) = OutCome : " + outcome);
        return outcome;
    }

    private void createElementBreadcrum(MenuItem menuItem, String outcome) {
        DefaultMenuItem menuItemBreadCrump = new DefaultMenuItem();
        menuItemBreadCrump.setValue(menuItem.getValue());
        menuItemBreadCrump.setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        menuItemBreadCrump.setOutcome(outcome);

        menuItemBreadCrump.setAjax(false); // TODO REMOVE AJAX TRANSACTION

        Logger.getInstance().log(Severity.DEBUG, LOG_FACILITY, "createElementBreadcrum(MenuActionEvent) = OutCome : " + outcome);
        this.breadCrump.addElement(menuItem);
    }

    /**
     * Set BEANAuth Managed Bean for Injection.
     * 
     * @param BEANAuthBean
     */
    public void setBEANAuth(BEANAuthBean BEANAuthBean) {
        BEANAuth = BEANAuthBean;
    }
}
```

Image of My Menu Created:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried many things and did not have a good result, could you help me please?

**UPDATE**

The problem is related to **component IDs** for some reason the component is changing the Ids to redirect the page.

Notice I did not generate the MenuModel component more than *once in no time*.

I tried to use the **.generateUniqueIds()** method, but it still fails

This is my log to view IDs Components, for one menu:

**First Redirect**

```
 getMenuModel = In here
getMenuModel = SIZE ELEMENTS 1
Sub Menu Name : Aceptación y Documentos > Sub Menu ID : 0 > Sub Menu ID CLIENT : 0
## Item Menu Name : Acepta Proceso > Item Menu ID : 0_0 > Item Menu ID CLIENT : 0_0
## Item Menu Name : Envio/Recepcion Documentos > Item Menu ID : 0_1 > Item Menu ID CLIENT : 0_1
```

**Second Redirect**

```
getMenuModel = In here
getMenuModel = SIZE ELEMENTS 1
Sub Menu Name : Aceptación y Documentos > Sub Menu ID : 0 > Sub Menu ID CLIENT : 0
## Item Menu Name : Acepta Proceso > Item Menu ID : 1 > Item Menu ID CLIENT : 1
## Item Menu Name : Envio/Recepcion Documentos > Item Menu ID : 1 > Item Menu ID CLIENT : 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my problemm with a new instance of the menu model and passing the elements already created each redirect.

If any person has a better answer, please add. Because I was not very happy with this solution.

```
private void refreshMenuModel() {
        List<MenuElement> elements = this.mainMenu.getElements();
        this.mainMenu = new DefaultMenuModel();
        for (MenuElement menuElement : elements) {
            this.mainMenu.addElement(menuElement);
        }
        generateUniqueIdsMenuModel();
    }


private void generateUniqueIdsMenuModel() {
    this.mainMenu.generateUniqueIds();
}
```